# Quicksort program - it's giving me type-error

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

```
def quick_sort(sequence):
    length = len(sequence)
    if length <= 1:
        return
    else:
        pivot = sequence.pop()

    items_g = []
    items_l = []

    for item in sequence:
        if item > pivot:
            items_g.append(item)
        else:
            items_l.append(item)

    return quick_sort(items_l) + [pivot] + quick_sort(items_g)


print(quick_sort([5, 89, 7, 41, 2]))
```

Comment: if length <= 1, this function will return None

Comment: (Non-in-place partition-exchange sorts like this will have unfavourable resource hunger. The `else:` following the base case is uncalled for.)

Answer (score 0):

You must return an empty list and not None

```
def quick_sort(sequence):
    length = len(sequence)
    if length <= 1:
        return []
    else:
        pivot = sequence.pop()

    items_g = []
    items_l = []

    for item in sequence:
        if item > pivot:
            items_g.append(item)
        else:
            items_l.append(item)

    return quick_sort(items_l) + [pivot] + quick_sort(items_g)


print(quick_sort([5, 89, 7, 41, 2]))
```